# Access to merge fields of Named credentials in apex context

Tags: apex, namedcredentials

I have to provide OAuth access token to a JS SDK, 
The JS is uploaded in Static resource and referenced in visualforce

```
JS_SDK.accessToken = '{!my_access_token}';
```

From Named credential documentation, I understand that in apex we can construct custom headers by doing

```
req.setHeader('Authorization', 'access_token {!$Credential.OAuthToken}');
```

I have defined the named credential, authenticated and
checked: `Allow Merge Fields in HTTP Header` & `Allow Merge Fields in HTTP Body` fields.

Is there a way to refer the `{!$Credential.OAuthToken}` in apex as a variable
and then refer in visualforce.

Does the merge field resolution only happen when the request is sent out ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the merge field is resolved only upon callout. This is an intentional design choice to avoid leaking the credentials unnecessarily. You would need to make the callout in Apex directly in order to take advantage of this feature.

Comment: Thanks sfdcfox!
In that case I have to handle the OAuth flow on my own, to get hold of the access token,